# Compile error due to position of Private Declare statement

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to use the alternative to `CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").GUID` provided on [this Microsoft support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4036837/run-time-error-70-permission-denied-generate-guid-with-office-vba) (with some modification) but get "Compile error: Only comments may appear after End Sub, End Function, or End Property" on the `Private Declare PtrSafe Function CoCreateGuid Lib "ole32.dll" (guid As GUID_TYPE) As LongPtr` line.

As can be seen in the code below, this line is within a function so I don't understand what is causing this compile error.

I tried to move the two `Private Declare` lines around within the function to see if that would solve the issue but continued to get the same error.

```vb
Public Function GetGUID() As String
  Private Type GUID_TYPE
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(7) As Byte
  End Type

  Private Declare PtrSafe Function CoCreateGuid Lib "ole32.dll" (guid As GUID_TYPE) As LongPtr
  Private Declare PtrSafe Function StringFromGUID2 Lib "ole32.dll" (guid As GUID_TYPE, ByVal lpStrGuid As LongPtr, ByVal cbMax As Long) As LongPtr

  Dim guid As GUID_TYPE
  Dim strGuid As String
  Dim retValue As LongPtr
  Const guidLength As Long = 39 'registry GUID format with null terminator {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
  retValue = CoCreateGuid(guid)
  If retValue = 0 Then
    strGuid = String$(guidLength, vbNullChar)
    retValue = StringFromGUID2(guid, StrPtr(strGuid), guidLength)
    If retValue = guidLength Then
      ' valid GUID as a string
      GetGUID = strGuid
    End If
  End If
End Function
```

This function is being used within a module meant to copy calendar events from the default calendar to another specified calendar.

This code can be found [here](https://blog.binarybits.net/programming/copy-new-appointments-one-calendar-another-calendar-using-vba/). Again, it replaces the `GetGUID = Mid$(CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").GUID, 2, 36)` line within this code.

What is causing this error and is there a solution?

Comment: The private type and function declarations need to be outside (above the first line) of your public function declaration.

Answer (score 4):

`Declare` statements belong at module level. Cut the two lines and move them at the very top of the module, just underneath where `Option Explicit` should be.

The compile error is a bit clumsy / misleading: it's the same compile error you would be getting if you had `Declare` statements or variable declarations *between* two procedures in the module.

```
Option Explicit
'legal here
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CoCreateGuid Lib "ole32.dll" (guid As GUID_TYPE) As LongPtr

Public Sub Foo()
End Sub

'illegal here
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CoCreateGuid Lib "ole32.dll" (guid As GUID_TYPE) As LongPtr

Private Function Bar()
    'illegal here
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CoCreateGuid Lib "ole32.dll" (guid As GUID_TYPE) As LongPtr
End Sub
```

`Declare` statements must live in the module's `(declarations)` section - watch the upper-left dropdown at the top of the code pane window: if it doesn't say `(declarations)`, then you're inside a procedure's scope; `Declare` statements can't be scoped at procedure level.